# How to stack views in React Native?

Tags: react-native

This might seem like a simple question but I need to stack a few differnt views on top of each other and hide/show them programatically. Each one would need to fill 100% width and height of the viewport and be layered on top of eact other.

In CSS I would simply do this.

```
.screen{
    width: 100%,
    height: 100%,
    position: absolute,
    z-index: 1 // Increasing as they stack
}
```

... but the react native equivelant didn't seem to work, the layer disappeared off screen completely. Also, I'm using Expo to show this on my android phone so don't have access to the dev-tools inspector as I would in Chrome to find out what's going wrong.

It might seem like what I need is a router here and I do intend to use one for for switching between my main routes but this is more to create a layered background effect which I need to sit behind all screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `top:0` and `left:0` also it is `zIndex` not `z-index`. Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  state = { screenToShow: 0 };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.changeScreen();
  }
  changeScreen() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(
        {
          screenToShow: (this.state.screenToShow + 1) % 4,
        },
        this.changeScreen
      );
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    const screenToShow = this.state.screenToShow;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={[
            styles.screen,
            { zIndex: screenToShow === 0 ? 1000 : -1, backgroundColor: 'red' },
          ]}
        />
        <View
          style={[
            styles.screen,
            { zIndex: screenToShow === 1 ? 1000 : -1, backgroundColor: 'blue' },
          ]}
        />
        <View
          style={[
            styles.screen,
            {
              zIndex: screenToShow === 2 ? 1000 : -1,
              backgroundColor: 'green',
            },
          ]}
         />
        <View
          style={[
            styles.screen,
             {
              zIndex: screenToShow === 3 ? 1000 : -1,
              backgroundColor: 'yellow',
            },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
   },
  screen: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect